# Gradle Flavor manifest files according to sdk version

Tags: android, sdk, gradle, manifest

I would like to use two different manifest files in a project according to the sdk version. Lets say that <2.3 versions will use manifest1.xml and >=2.3 versions will use manifest2.xml. Is there a way to achieve this?